# python cx-freeze executable and original python file look different

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I made a python file, it uses the module `tkinter.messagebox`, I made it an executable file using `cx-freeze` , but the `messagebox` from the executable looks different from the `messagebox` made with the python code.
[messagebox looks different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA0nc.png)

how do I make the executable's `messagebox` look like the `messagebox` made using the python code?

here is my cx-freeze script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(  name = "script",
        version = "1.1",
        description = "messages",
        options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["os"]}},
        executables = [Executable("msg.py", base="win32gui")])
```

to make the exe, I typed `python setup.py build` in the command line.

also, please don't ask me to use `pyinstaller` because there's problems with it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `pyinstaller` to make the executable instead, it worked finally.
I think it's something to do with the `win32gui` base. in pyinstaller, when i used the `-w` parameter, the messagebox also looks like the ugly one.